# Azure YAML Pipelines: Is it possible to find out which pipeline triggered a build?

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, devops

I have two repos on my Azure DevOps project. One for the Cloud Infrastructure deployment and another that contains my application code.

I have a YAML pipeline that is triggered after any of those repos build pipeline finishes. The pipeline looks a bit like this like this:

```
resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: MyProject-Code
  - pipeline: MyProject-Infrastructure
  
jobs:
- job: DeployInfrastructure
  steps:
  # Here are the tasks the deploy the project infrastructure

- job: DeployCode
  steps:
  # Here are the tasks that deploy the code
```

I would like to put a condition on the DeployInfrastructure job so it is only executed if the triggering pipeline is the infrastructure one as I do not need to redeploy it if the change only affects the application code.

However, when reading the [documentation from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/pipeline-triggers?view=azure-devops) there does not seem to be a very straightforward way of doing this.

Comment: did you actually find a solution to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [Pipeline resource variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/resources?view=azure-devops&tabs=example#pipeline-resource-variables)

> In each run, the metadata for a pipeline resource is available to all
> jobs in the form of predefined variables. The  is the
> identifier that you gave for your pipeline resource. Pipeline
> resources variables are only available at runtime.

There are also a number of [predefined variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables) called `Build.TriggeredBy.*`, amongst them `Build.TriggeredBy.DefinitionName`, however documentation suggests that for yaml pipeline with pipeline triggers the resource variables should be used instead

> If the build was triggered by another build, then this variable is set
> to the name of the triggering build pipeline. In Classic pipelines,
> this variable is triggered by a build completion trigger.
>
> This variable is agent-scoped, and can be used as an environment
> variable in a script and as a parameter in a build task, but not as
> part of the build number or as a version control tag.
>
> If you are triggering a YAML pipeline using resources, you should use
> the resources variables instead.